# Prob. 7, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: Every bounded set has outer measure equal to a $G_\delta$ set containing it

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Here is Prob. 7, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> A set of real numbers is said to be a $G_\delta$ set provided it is the intersection of a countable collection of open sets. Show that for any bounded set $E$, there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ for which
> $$
> E \subseteq G \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad m^*(G) = m^*(E). 
> $$

My Attempt:

> Note that, for any subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the outer measure $m^*(E)$ by definition is the infimum (or greatest lower bound) of the set of all the sums of the form $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty l \left( I_k \right)$, where $\left\{ I_k \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a countable collection of non-empty bounded, open intervals such that $E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$.

> Let $E$ be a (non-empty) bounded set of the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers. Then $E$ has an infimum $\alpha$ and a supremum $\beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, and we have the inclusion
> $$
> E \subseteq [\alpha, \beta ],
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> m^*(E) \leq m^* \big( [\alpha, \beta] \big) = l \big( [\alpha, \beta] \big) = \beta - \alpha < +\infty, 
> $$
> by virtue of Proposition 1 in Royden. In short $m^*(E) < +\infty$, that is, $m^*(E)$ is a non-negative real number.

> Now for each positive integer $n$, as $m^*(E)$ is the infinum (or greatest lower bound) of a particular sum and as
> $$ m^*(E) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}, $$
> so there exists a countable colletion $\left\{ I_{nk} \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that
> $$
> E \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{nk} \tag{1} 
> $$
> and
> $$
> m^*(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{nk} \right) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}; \tag{2} 
> $$
> let us put
> $$
> U_n := \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{nk}. \tag{Definition 1}
> $$
> Then each set $U_n$ being a union of bounded open intervals on the real line is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ and we also have
> $$ E \subseteq U_n $$
> by (1) above.

> Now let us put
> $$
> G := \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n. \tag{Definition 2} 
> $$
> This set $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set of real numbers, and we also have $E \subseteq G$, which implies
> $$
> m^*(E) \leq m^*(G), \tag{3} 
> $$
> by the monotonicity of the outer measure.

> For each positive integer $n$, since $G \subset U_n$ [Refer to (Definition 2) above.], therefore we also have
> $$
> m^*(G) \leq m^* \left( U_n \right). \tag{4} 
> $$
> Therefore for each positive integer $n$ we have
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \   m^*(G) \\ 
> &\leq m^* \left( U_n \right) \\ 
> &= m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{nk} \right) \qquad [\mbox{ refer to (Definition 1) above }] \\
> &\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^* \left( I_{nk} \right) \qquad [ \mbox{ by Proposition 3 in Royden } ] \\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{nk} \right) \qquad [ \mbox{ by Proposition 1 in Royden } ] \\ 
> &< m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}, \qquad [ \mbox{ by virtue of  (2) above } ]
> \end{align}
> which implies
> $$
> m^*(G) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}, 
> $$
> and upon taking the limits of both sides of this last inequality as $n \to \infty$, we obtain
> $$
> m^*(G) \leq m^*(E), 
> $$
> which together with (3) above gives
> $$
> m^*(G) = m^*(E), 
> $$
> as required.

Is my proof correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there any issues in any portion of it?

Comment: Your proof is “the” proof. It is exactly what I’d do and exactly what most would do, I think

Comment: Things could get much simpler if you observe that any open set is a countable union of open intervals. Then you can simply take the infimum over the open sets containing $E$. Now, take a (decreasing if you prefer) sequence of open sets $U_n \supset E$ such that $m^*(U_n) \downarrow m^*(E)$.

Comment: Of course, $E \subset G \subset U_n$ implies that $m^*(E) \leq m^*(G) \leq m^*(U_n)$. And therefore, $m^*(G) = m^*(E)$.